# How to get weekly report using mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I have table format like below.

```
Customer_ID   Result C_Date
1              2      2017-06-19 15:49:00
1              3      2017-06-20 15:49:00
1              3      2017-06-21 15:49:00
2              1      2017-06-15 15:49:00
3              2      2017-06-15 15:49:00
1              2      2017-06-19 19:49:00
1              3      2017-06-21 23:49:00
```

I need to get all records of Customer_ID is 1 and result of current week.
For Example

```
Customer_ID  Day     Total(COUNT)
1            Sunday    0
1            Monday    2
1            Tuesday   1
1            Wednesday 1
1            Thursday  0
1            Friday    0
1            Saturday  0
```

i need this type of result in mysql query.

Comment: Worth a read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: Have you tried to write a query yet?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
**SO is not** a free Coding service ___We try to fix your code, we do not write your code___

Comment: Yes that is possible. Care to share what you have tried? Are you supplying a date range?

Comment: here's some ideas: select from a row source that is guaranteed to provide the 7 `Day` values ("Sunday" thru "Saturday"); an outer join to your table, with condition in the ON clause that limits the rows to those in a specific date range, and matching `Day` to `DATE_FORMAT(t.c_date,'%W')`, a `GROUP BY` clause to collapse the rows, and a `COUNT()` aggregate.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: One issue you will have is generating rows for days that do not exist in your source table. Again, you haven't shown what you have tried. Take a look in the help section for how to ask a question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the WEEKOFYEAR() function:

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-weekofyear-function.php

So, do something like WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(C_DATE) = WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())

I suspect that this will be dreadfully slow. Maybe a better way would be to find the start and end dates of the current week, then use them to do a < and > against C_Date.

Mick

Comment: need data for current week.

Comment: Why don't you start writing a SELECT and let's see what you get?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will return the specified result:

```
SELECT c.customer_id   AS `Customer_ID`
     , d.day           AS `Day`
     , COUNT(1)        AS `Total(COUNT)`
  FROM ( SELECT 1 AS customer_id ) c
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT 1 AS `dow`, 'Sunday' AS `day`
         UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'Monday'
         UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'Tuesday'
         UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'Wednesday'
         UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'Thursday'
         UNION ALL SELECT 6, 'Friday'
         UNION ALL SELECT 7, 'Saturday'
       ) d
  LEFT
  JOIN mytable t
    ON t.customer_id = c.customer_id
   AND t.c_date >= DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -7 DAY
   AND t.c_date <  DATE(NOW())
   AND DAYOFWEEK(t.c_date) = d.dow
 GROUP BY c.customer_id, d.dow
 ORDER BY c.customer_id, d.dow
```

---

NOTE:

We need a rowsource that returns the seven "Day" values (Sunday thru Saturday), otherwise, we can't return a "zero" count for that day from the table, when there isn't a row for that day.

We need to define "current week". The query above uses the current date, and subtracts seven days. If this query runs on a Wednesday, we'll get the seven preceding days, Wednesday thru Tuesday. If your definition of "current week" is different than that, then use expressions that generate the a DATETIME value at the beginning of the reporting period, and the first second after the reporting period (in place of `DATE(NOW)) + INTERVAL -7 DAY` and `DATE(NOW))`)

---

**FOLLOWUP**

addressing comment: "only get Mondays records, all others not right"

Please understand this: StackOverflow is *not* a query and code writing service.
The answer above illustrates an example of a query *pattern*, addressing one of the biggest humps the query needs to get over:

- returning zero counts for rows that don't exist

As the answer noted above (under that line that says NOTE:) we need an actual  specification for "current week". What does that mean when "today" is Tuesday, `'2017-06-20'`. What range of dates does that specify?  And what does that mean if today is Friday, or Sunday?

Once we have a definition, we can then write *expressions* that will return the beginning and end date values.

To put that another way, ... take this part of the query:

```
   AND t.c_date >= DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -7 DAY
   AND t.c_date <  DATE(NOW())
```

And replace that with something like this:

```
   AND t.c_date >= '2017-06-14'
   AND t.c_date <  '2017-06-21'
```

or like this:

```
   AND t.c_date >= '2017-06-18'
   AND t.c_date <  '2017-06-25'
```

What date *literals* can be used so the query returns the expected result? So that the query is NOT "*only get Mondays records, all others not right*" [sic].

We can use a simple SELECT statement to test expressions. We can use a user-defined variable in place of NOW() to test with a variety of possible values for NOW().  For example:

```
SET @tday = '2017-06-21 12:34' ;

SELECT DATE(@tday) - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(@tday)-1 DAY AS sd
     , DATE(@tday) - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(@tday)-8 DAY AS ed
```

Once we have expressions that return the "start" and "end" of the range, we can make use those in another query. Like the one above...

```
   AND t.c_date >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-1 DAY
   AND t.c_date <  DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-8 DAY
```